# Establish connection between 2 computers on internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, remoting

I am having a domain name and web space (the web is running, its ASP.net 3.5). I am working on a project in which I need to connect 2 computers over the internet.

Is it possible to do that with a simple ASP.Net website? What other things I do need to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Actually I want to send the data from one computer to another in real time, I mean as we do chatting we exchange text to one another. The same thing I want to achieve.

Comment: What does **connect** exactly mean? File sharing, printers, desktop, RDP, running applications....

Comment: You have to clarify, what you want to achieve? To connect two computers its enough to call the "ping" command, which transfers a small amount of data between two computers - but i don't think thats what you want to know.

Comment: concentrate real hard :D

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to connect two computers and transfer data.

The most current and recommended approaches are:

- Go the high level way and use WCF: See the [WCF chat sample on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929%28VS.90%29.aspx)
- Go the low level way and use sockets/TCP: See the [socket chat sample on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx)
- Another low level approach using sockets/UDP: See the [UDP chat sample in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ChatAppAsynchUDPSocks.aspx)
- You can also program an ASP.NET chat application like shown in this [ASP.NET sample on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/AliAspNetChat.aspx)
- And last but not least, you can use [MSMQ for chatting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Chat_Using_MSMQ.aspx) too

Answer (score 1):

To go through NAT routers and firewalls you probably have to implement something like "Session Traversal Utilities for NAT" (STUN) or "Traversal Using Relay NAT" (TURN).

Other techniques are "[UDP Hole Punching](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html#SECTION00030000000000000000)" or "[TCP Hole Punching](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html#SECTION00040000000000000000)".

I also found an article about a [STUN client in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/STUN_client.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly want? If one computer opens a web site hosted on the other - they are connected :)

You can, for example, create a web service on the computer running ASP.NET and use its functionality from the other.

Or, maybe you want connect them using sockets?